# run artisan command from php function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I want to run `php artisan passport:client --password` from function.

I tryed `Artisan::call('passport:client');` and `Artisan::command('passport:client');` but it return `undefined command`

**Note: I have alredy install laravel passport and the command is working fine from the terminal**

Comment: what's is the artisan output, is the command in the list?

Comment: this command should create client and it has parameters (name)

Comment: Did you resolved this issue? I'm running into this, and I'm lost.

Answer (score 5):

I have found it, in `boot()` method of the `PassportServiceProvider` there is a check that essentially prevent it being called from `Artisan::call`.

```
//PassportServiceProvider.php at line 37: 

if ($this->app->runningInConsole()) {

$this->commands([
    Console\InstallCommand::class,
    Console\ClientCommand::class,
    Console\KeysCommand::class,
]);
...
}
```

to make it work with general artisan command, we can register these commands ourselves. somewhere within the boot method of `AuthServiceProvider` maybe.

```
public function boot() {
    $this->commands([
        Console\InstallCommand::class,
        Console\ClientCommand::class,
        Console\KeysCommand::class,
    ]);
}
```

Now we can call `Artisan::call('passport:install')` or the other 2 commands.

Answer (score 4):

From Laravel Docs

```
Route::get('/foo', function () {
$exitCode = Artisan::call('email:send', [
    'user' => 1, '--queue' => 'default'
]);

//
});
```

Comment: it returns "There are no commands defined in the "passport" namespace."

Comment: is this right 
`Artisan::call('passport:client', ['name' => 'ads', '--password' => 'default']);`

Answer (score 0):

Import this line on top.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
```

And Enter line below for command

```
Artisan::call('passport:client --password')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).