# Can't run laravel artisan command in the unit test

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

I have Laravel framework `v5.8.29`.

And I can't run artisan command in a unit test either using `$this->artisan()` nor `Artisan::call()`.

`migrate` command prints absolutely nothing.

It seems like the command just even was not called!

But it works pretty well if I call the command from the system, using `php artisan migrate`.

Example: https://travis-ci.com/github/CaliforniaMountainSnake/laravel-database-test-case/builds/171804872

As you can see, at first I call `php artisan migrate` directly and it works as expected.
But then I call the same command from the unit test and it just doesn't work.
A second time I call `migrate` command with another empty database, so the first call doesn't affect the second (You can see the proof of that, `TABLES of "test_mysql"` returns nothing).

Comment: Check this article. I hope it'll solve your proble.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41615268/run-artisan-command-from-php-function

Comment: MeGaZ, I already found that command actually runs, but doesn't produce any output: https://github.com/laravel/framework/discussions/33242 This is strange behavior, you can see this in this library: https://travis-ci.com/github/CaliforniaMountainSnake/laravel-database-test-case